# Can I take a GPL program and relicense my changes under the AGPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl, agpl

Can I take a GPL program and relicense my changes under the AGPL?

Say I clone a GPL project, make some changes, can I only allow people to use my changes under the AGPL license?

Answer (score 3):

[According to the FSF, you cannot](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#AGPLv3.0):

> Please note that the GNU AGPL is not compatible with GPLv2. It is also
>   technically not compatible with GPLv3 in a strict sense: **you cannot
>   take code released under the GNU AGPL and convey or modify it however
>   you like under the terms of GPLv3, or vice versa**. However, you are
>   allowed to combine separate modules or source files released under
>   both of those licenses in a single project, which will provide many
>   programmers with all the permission they need to make the programs
>   they want. See section 13 of both licenses for details.

I believe the "vice versa" covers the exact case you're asking about.

If I'm reading that FAQ item and [section 13 of the AGPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html#section13) correctly, the closest thing that you are allowed to do is combine GPL'd code with AGPL'd code into a single product. But even in that case the two pieces of code retain their respective licenses.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I take a GPL program and resilience my changes under the AGPL?

No, you are not allowed to change the licence. GPL code has to contain the GPL, and it is not allowed to change the licence.

> Say I clone a GPL project, make some changes, can I only allow people to use my changes under the AGPL license?

See above : you are not allowed to modify the licence. If you clone the project, you can publish your changes only under GPL conditions.